# Адаптивная вёрстка емайла

Tags: android, css, iphone, email

Стоит задача делать адаптивный емайл. Но, как оказалось медиа запросы и вьюпорт не отрабатывают, а приложение gmail само увеличивает текст. Подскажите, плиз, 
 как можно подключить @media, как можно побороть самостоятельное увеличение текста в приложении gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в мире существует целый зоопарк почтовых клиентов (настольных, с веб-серсивом или мобильных). И весь этот зоопарк живёт в прошлом тысячелетии.

Вопрос абсолютно нетривиальный, вам придётся более глубоко в него вникнуть.

> Например, в «нативном» почтовом Android-клиенте media queries поддерживаются, однако на устрйоствах Samsung с той же ОС — нет (даже в нативном клиенте). Так происходит, поскольку Samsung заменила «дефолтное» почтовое приложение на клиент собственной разработки. Для того, чтобы сделать письма адаптивными в этом приложении используется техника гибридного программирования.
>
> Поскольку media queries поддерживаются далеко не всеми приложениями, дизайнерам почтовых рассылок приходится прибегать к различным ухищрениям, которые помогают создать письма, лучше выглядящие на мобильных устройствах.

Вот хорошая статья про media queries в рассылках: [Использование media queries в вёрстке email-писем: за и против](http://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/258313/)

Прикрепляю табличку из этой статьи:

[image: Поддержка Media Queries почтовыми клиентами]

Эти же авторы пишут о том насколько сложно верстать письма и как это лучше делать:

[5 правил верстки email-писем от Печкина](http://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/182964/)

[Как использовать прогрессивное улучшение для вёрстки писем](http://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/257915/)